# Python Scrapy issue: Frontend package has been deprecated

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using 32-bit Python 2.7. I believe I have successfully installed Scrapy and all the dependencies. When I type `scrapy version` in the cmd prompt, it shows the version. But when I try to scrape the home page of Wikipedia for testing, this is the output:

**The last few lines go as follows :**

```
C:\...\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend,py:30: UserWarning: The top-level 'frontend' package has been deprecated. All its subpackages have been moved to the top 'IPython' level.
warn<"The top-level 'frontend' package has been deprecated.

In[1]:"
```

Note: I have installed IPython and its dependencies. And I have no idea what "frontend" and "deprecated" mean? Any idea of how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: It means that the package `frontend` should no longer be used. That's what deprecated means. If code is marked as deprecated, the author has determined that the code was unsafe or should no longer be used because a newer version is available.

Comment: But what is calling from the package frontend? Scrapy? Ipython? How can I stop them using frontend?